# OIDC Disconnect in Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi, openid-connect

I have set up a OIDC on my nifi standalone instance, it works great and all but if i idle for more than 5 mintues it redirects me to an Unauthorized window message and says 
"Unknown user with identity anonymous".
Refreshing solves this, however, is there a way to make sure to extend the connection, or a workaround to avoid these disconnects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone is struck with a similar problem, 
my solution is to overwrite the NAR file responsible to OIDCAuthentication (just increasing the expiration timer hehe)
its not a pleasant solution but it will do for the time being, until nifi supports refresh tokens or adds a feature to customize session duration.

stay updated at
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-4890

Comment: Were you able to resolve it? facing similar issue with 1.17. openid JWT token is expiring in 5mins.

Comment: @StrangerThinks sadly no, same hack as before

Comment: can you DM me what changes you made to have custom timeout? What exact changes were done? Much thanks!

Comment: Sadly I don't have access to the code anymore, so first try to talk with idp to extend the token expedition time, and based on my not so great memory it should be something like this:

Comment: @StrangerThinks https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/dfa683af0e00cd631905d45365bc797fbdce66ee/nifi-registry/nifi-registry-core/nifi-registry-web-api/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/registry/web/security/authentication/oidc/StandardOidcIdentityProvider.java. look at line 372, I would extend the expiration. Again, Not sure this would work

Answer (score 1):

It depends on used Identity Provider (IdP) - it generates token with preconfigured time validity. Usually, it can be configured on the client configuration level, but it is recommended to have short time validity. OIDC offers option how to renew access token, but it depends on used flow. It can be refreshed via refresh tokens (grant code flow) or silent refresh (implicit flow). It is not clear which IdP and flow is used in your case, so you can get only these general recommendation.

Comment: I see, we have pepole in charge of that so il direct the questions to them. I will post an answer as an update!

Comment: My IdP can provide refresh tokens, but does nifi supports refresh tokens? I havent seen anything in the source code

Comment: indeed nifi doesnt support refresh tokens! 
Voice your opinion on the matter:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-4890